# Rearrange Date input field rendering

Tags: forms, datetime, theming

In a function that is a response to a drupal_get_form() I am constructing a form that includes a date field

```
$form['dob'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#date_format' => 'm-d-Y',
    '#title' => 'Date of Birth',
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

This however displays the the input with year first then month and date. How can I change this to render the month first then day and then year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `#type` value to `date_select`

So your code should look like this

```
$form['dob'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_select',
    '#date_format' => 'm-d-Y',
    '#title' => 'Date of Birth',
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

If you want text field instead of select dropdown menu you can change `date_select` to `date_text`

Comment: I needed to add a '#date_year_range' to have more then the last few years but this worked, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you.